# how to create a javascript countdown which on refreshing continues counting

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, timeout, countdown

I try it with javascript and jquery but no idea how to do that. i wont to let the timer not begins on refreshing counting again. It´s same as an auction when he counting down 3,2 and on refreshing he don´t begins again it should continue count down where it last ended. And on other products it must count from 3 again. Have anyboy an idea?

**Edit:** because some users missunderstood what i am searching for.

my issue is that i don´t know how to save the time when someone refresh the page to continue to count it down. if someone refresh the site at 21sec and he or she have 30 secs to make there choice. and after refreshing the site, the counter will count at 21sec down and not started again by 30sec again.
no ajax.

When possible hardcoded. 
And if not possible then the cookie variant.

Comment: `document.cookie`, or `localStorage`, or hard-coded `Date` value.

Comment: a hard-coded `Date` value only works if you're counting down to a specific date, such as, say, New Years. If you've got relative times based off the user you *need* to use a `cookie` or localstorage. That doesn't mean that you have to set the cookie in JS, you'd be better off using a server script to store a session value for the user, but sessions rely on cookies too.

Comment: ok i thought so but i didn´t let javascript die until i do not know what it can do only hardcoded. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Perfect but I designed this script to do a 30min countdown and then to change some text during the last few seconds. The only issue with it is that when it gets to 1:00 it starts at 30:60 and I haven't figured out how to fix that yet. This may not work perfectly for what your looking for but it might put you on the right path.

```
<script>
//add leading zeros
setInterval(function() {
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
var x = document.getElementById("timer");
var d = new Date();
var s = (d.getSeconds());
var m = (d.getMinutes());
var a = addZero(30 - m);
var b = addZero(60 - m);
var c = (60 - s);
var z = "<span style='color:red;font-size:50px;'>" + "Break" + "</span>";
var v = "<span style='color:black;font-size:24px;'>" + "Break" + "</span>";
//Decide how much should be subtracted from the time
if (m > 30) {
    y = b;
}
else if (m < 30) {
    y = a;
}
//elements for changing text
if (y < 2 && c < 15) {
    q = z;
}
else {
    q = v;
}

var t = y + (":" + addZero(c) + " Till Station " + (q));
x.innerHTML = t;
}, 250);
</script>


<div align="center" id="timer" style='color:black;font-size:24px;' ></div>
```

Comment: I wanted to add that because this script is based on the system clock, refreshing the page will not change the time. The script basically gets the current time, then begins to subtract from that. So even if you refreshed the page, the time remaining would stay the same. In the end you will probably have to store the date in a cookie, then calculate based on the cookie information.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a name to your window on load of the page. Before setting the name check whether this window already has a name.

if it doesn't have a name, set a name to the window and start counting at 0 and save the count value in a cookie each time it increment.

if it does have a name(that means page is reloaded), read the count value from the cookie and do the increment and save to cookie.

**EDIT**:  Example, Call initCount() function on body load. Use decrementAndSave function to decrement the value of the count and save it to cookie.

```
var count = 3;// 3 -> 2 -> 1

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function initCount() {
    if (window.name) {
        count = getCookie("count_" + window.name);// to keep separate count cookies for each window    
    } else {
        window.name = "w_" + (new Date().getTime());
        count = 3;
        setCookie("count_" + window.name, count, null);
    }
}

function decrementAndSave() {
    count--;
    // separate cookie for each window or tab
    setCookie("count_" + window.name, count, null);
}
```

Comment: this seems so easly omg ^^ i will try it but @zzzzBov ask for hardcode with `Date` what i try all night to do. is this possible and how.
and thank you very!

Comment: @webfacer I have added some example code to the post. I think you can modify and use it according to your need. You may need to add setTimeout function for calling the decrementAndSave function each second or add a condition for what happen when count becomes zero etc. Sorry, Actually I have no idea what zzzzBov meant by "hard code with Date".

Comment: thanks i will try it today and let you know if it works fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you have a countdown, then you must have some sort of end time defined. So instead of having a countdown and just subtracting 1 every second, try something like this:

```
var endTime = new Date(2011,11,13,0,0,0); // Midnight of December 13th 2011
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeleft = Math.max(0,Math.floor((endTime.getTime()-now.getTime())/1000));

    var d, h, m, s;
    s = timeleft % 60;
    timeleft = Math.floor(timeleft/60);
    m = timeleft % 60;
    timeleft = Math.floor(timeleft/60);
    h = timeleft % 24;
    timeleft = Math.floor(timeleft/24);
    d = timeleft;

    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "Time left: "+d+" days, "+h+" hours, "+m+" minutes, "+s+" seconds.";

    if( timeleft == 0) clearInterval(timer);
},1000);
```

Comment: sry thats not that what i am searching for. i know that i have an endtime. my issue is that i don´t know how to save if someone refresh the page to continue to count it down. if someone refresh the site at 21sec and he or she have 30 secs to make there choice. and after refresh the counter will count at 21sec down and not started again by 30sec again.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var interval = 90000; //90 secounds

      function reset() {
        localStorage.endTime = +new Date() + interval;
      }

      if (!localStorage.endTime) {
        reset();
      }
      function millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
        var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
        var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;
       }
      setInterval(function () {
        var remaining = localStorage.endTime - new Date();
        if (remaining >= 0) {
          document.getElementById("tooltip").innerText =
            millisToMinutesAndSeconds(remaining);
        } else {
          reset();
        }
      }, 100);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.